# if with || giving Syntax error on token "||", invalid Expression

Tags: java

hi I'm new to coding (like one week new to it) and am taking a class for it wants me to write a program to calculate shipping charges and i need to use if with a or and it gives me an error

**Syntax error on token "||", invalid Expression**

````
 charge = length * width * hight;

       if(charge = 5.1> || <15) {
           charge = 14;
       } ```
````

Comment: One `=` is assignment. And you have no comparison on the right hand side of `||`. What should `|| 15` (or fifteen) do?

Comment: if think `if(charge>5.1 || charge<15)` is what you are looking for

Comment: If length * width * height + weight is:

Between 5.1 and 15, the charge is 14.00 this was from the assignment

Comment: f1sh thanks that fixed it

Comment: `if (charge >= 5.1 && charge <= 15)`